# spring-boot @autowired interface (CrudRepository) in my Service class => Null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, autowired

I have my public interface with some methods

```
@Repository
public interface JobHistoryRepository extends CrudRepository<JobHistory, Long> {

    List<JobHistory> findByJobGroup(String jobGroup);
    JobHistory findById (Integer id);
    List<JobHistory> findByStateAndJobGroup(String state, String jobGroup);
    JobHistory findByJobNameAndJobGroupAndIdTrigger (String jobName, String jobGroup, String idTrigger);

}
```

I want use it in myclass Service

```
@Service
public class JobHistoryService {

    @Autowired
    private JobHistoryRepository jobHistoryRepository;


    public void setReadyJob(String jobId, String tenant, String idTrigger) {
    JobHistory jobHistory = new JobHistory();
     jobHistory.setJobName(jobId);
     jobHistory.setJobGroup(tenant);
     jobHistory.setIdTrigger(idTrigger);
     jobHistory.setIdUser("12345");
     jobHistory.setState("Ready");
     jobHistory.setDateCreation(new Date());

     jobHistoryRepository.save(jobHistory);   <--- at this point jobHistoryrespository is null why?
    }
```

EDIT:
I have added both `@service` and `@repository` annonation to my classes but this still not working. Every time i use JobHistoryService method the jobRepository dependency is still null.

Let me know if i had to add more informations.
Thanks.

Comment: Show your spring boot configuration then.

Comment: Did you make sure that the class calling your service also autowired the service instead of using "new JobHistoryService()"? This can also be the cause for NPEs at such places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have interface be like this:

```
public interface JobHistoryRepository extends CrudRepository<JobHistory, Long> {

    List<JobHistory> findByJobGroup(String jobGroup);
    JobHistory findById (Integer id);
    List<JobHistory> findByStateAndJobGroup(String state, String jobGroup);
    JobHistory findByJobNameAndJobGroupAndIdTrigger (String jobName, String jobGroup, String idTrigger);
}
```

Then create a service class like :

```
@Service
public class JobHistoryService {

    private final JobHistoryRepository jobHistoryRepository;

    public JobHistoryService (final JobHistoryRepository jobHistoryRepository)
    {
        this.jobHistoryRepository = jobHistoryRepository;
    }

    public void setReadyJob(String jobId, String tenant, String idTrigger) {
    JobHistory jobHistory = new JobHistory();
     jobHistory.setJobName(jobId);
     jobHistory.setJobGroup(tenant);
     jobHistory.setIdTrigger(idTrigger);
     jobHistory.setIdUser("12345");
     jobHistory.setState("Ready");
     jobHistory.setDateCreation(new Date());

     jobHistoryRepository.save(jobHistory);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: On my opinion this is a bad workaround. What if you need a lot of "autowired" classes or interfaces?

Comment: write this :        private final JobHistoryRepository jobHistoryRepository;

    public JobHistoryService (final JobHistoryRepository jobHistoryRepository)
    {
        this.jobHistoryRepository = jobHistoryRepository;
    }
is equals to write this :     @Autowired
    private JobHistoryRepository jobHistoryRepository;

but when a have write first solution IDE has help me to find error:
i have use a new operator in another class.

Comment: Have you tried with @ComponentScan on your spring boot application class?

Comment: Alternatively, you can refer this example as well http://www.javainterviewpoint.com/spring-boot-crudrepository-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
JobHistoryService
```

should be also a Spring bean. Annotate it e.g. with `@Service`.

```
@Service
public class JobHistoryService {
...
}
```

Comment: @DavideBoldrin Have you checked your application will scan the package where the service class located?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this annotation

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.blabla.example.*"})
```

on your Spring Boot Application Class and check that the your repository interface are included on that path.

My Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.blabla.gg.*"})
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```